# How to use custom metric from a callback with EarlyStopping or ModelCheckpoint?

Tags: keras, callback

I want to use my custom metric from callback within another callback like EarlyStopping or ModelCheckpoint. But I need somehow save/store/log this custom metric such that other callback can access this?

I have:

```
class Metrics(keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def on_train_begin(self, logs={}):

        self.precision = []
        self.f1s = []
        self.prc=0
        self.f1s=0

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
        score = np.asarray(self.model.predict([self.validation_data[0],self.validation_data[1]]))
        predict = np.round(np.asarray(self.model.predict([self.validation_data[0],self.validation_data[1]])))
        targ = self.validation_data[2]

        predict = (predict < 0.5).astype(np.float)


        self.prc=sklm.precision_score(targ, predict)
        self.f1s=sklm.f1_score(targ, predict)
        self.precision.append(prc)
        self.f1s.append(f1s)

        print("— val_f1: %f — val_precision: %f" %(self.f1s, self.prc))
        return
```

Now,

```
metrics = Metrics()

es = EarlyStopping(monitor=metrics.prc, mode='max', verbose=1, patience=3,min_delta=0.01,restore_best_weights=True)

model.compile(loss=contrastive_loss, optimizer=adam)
model.fit([train_sen1, train_sen2], train_labels,
          batch_size=512,
          epochs=20,callbacks=[metrics,es],
          validation_data=([dev_sen1, dev_sen2], dev_labels))
```

doesn't work since Earlystopping does not know about the custom precision metric?

Does someone knows about this log statements of callbacks? Can I svae my metric there.

Answer (score 7):

To understand what's really going on here you have to go check the source code of the EarlyStopping and ModelCheckpoint classes on github. You can find it [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/EarlyStopping).

The problem in your code is that you don't update the "logs" dictionary you have in the "on_epoch_end" function. It's in that dictionary that the classes EarlyStopping and ModelCheckpoint go looking for what you have defined as being the "monitor".

So in your situation, if you were to use your precision score as a monitor your code should go as follows:

```
class Metrics(keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def on_train_begin(self, logs={}):

        self.precision = []
        self.f1scores = []
        self.prc=0
        self.f1s=0

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
        score = np.asarray(self.model.predict([self.validation_data[0],self.validation_data[1]]))
        predict = np.round(np.asarray(self.model.predict([self.validation_data[0],self.validation_data[1]])))
        targ = self.validation_data[2]

        predict = (predict < 0.5).astype(np.float)


        self.prc=sklm.precision_score(targ, predict)
        self.f1s=sklm.f1_score(targ, predict)
        self.precision.append(prc)
        self.f1scores.append(f1s)

        #Here is where I update the logs dictionary:
        logs["prc"]=self.prc
        logs["f1s"]=self.f1s

        print("— val_f1: %f — val_precision: %f" %(self.f1s, self.prc))
```

You can then call on these custom metrics in both CheckpointModel and EarlyStopping. Be sure however to put these callbacks in the correct order in your fit_generator: metrics should be put first otherwise your logs won't be updated when you run your EarlyStopping.

```
metrics = Metrics()

es = EarlyStopping(monitor="prc", mode='max', verbose=1, patience=3,min_delta=0.01,restore_best_weights=True)

model.compile(loss=contrastive_loss, optimizer=adam)
model.fit([train_sen1, train_sen2], train_labels,
          batch_size=512,
          epochs=20,callbacks=[metrics,es],
          validation_data=([dev_sen1, dev_sen2], dev_labels))
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Goldie!

Comment: What is ```validation_data[0]``` in your code. Because I receive ```TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable```

Answer (score 3):

zealous_nightingale's answer works well for `EarlyStopping` callback, however, for `ModelCheckpoint` callback you might additionally need to set `_supports_tf_logs` flag to `False` so that updated `log` dictionary is passed to the callback:

```
weights_path = 'checkpoint-{epoch:02d}-{customer_metric_name:.4f}.h5'
checkpoint = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(weights_path, monitor='customer_metric_name')
checkpoint._supports_tf_logs = False
```